# How to Load Tensorflow 1.1x Checkpoint weights into a TF2.2 LSTM layer - results are different (Python, Keras)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have an old TF1.1x checkpoint including an LSTM layer, and I also have layer activations from an earlier run, for each layer of the old network. I'm trying to recreate this network in TF2.2 and Keras using Python.
The Layer used in the old network was a  'tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockFusedCell'.

I split the LSTM-kernel weights from the checkpoint into corresponding 'Kernel', and 'Recurrent_kernel', and load these separately into an LSTM layer in TF2.2 (and the 'Bias' as well).

However, when I run a model.prediction with the old activations, I get a completely different output from the new LSTM layer, compared with the old model activation.

I have only loaded the above, that is: Kernel, Recurrent_Kernel and Bias weights.  No other parameters for this layer.

I hope to have extracted the salient points in the below code snippet:

```
# Create minimalistic Model, and Build it
#
modelC = keras.Sequential()
modelC.add( keras.layers.Reshape([-1,2048], name='l4_lstm' ))   
modelC.add( keras.layers.LSTM( units=2048 ) )

modelC.build(input_shape = (batch_size, 2048))


# Load Weights from Checkpoint Dictionary 'ckptdict', 
#
weights_ds = []
weights_ds.append(ckptdict['lstm_fused_cell/kernel'][:2048] ) # "W" 
weights_ds.append(ckptdict['lstm_fused_cell/kernel'][2048:] ) # "U" 
weights_ds.append(ckptdict['lstm_fused_cell/bias'])           # "b" 
modelC.set_weights(weights_ds)

# Run the minimal model on Activations from last layer before LSTM 
# (data corresponding to the Checkpointed TF1.1x model)
#
l3pred = modelC.predict( l3 )

# At this point, l3pred is wildly different from the TF1.1x version,
#
```

A similar method of importing weights works correctly (== same results with the old activations) for the other layers of the network, which are all "Dense", but the LSTM layer eludes me.

Can anyone point to a description that explains how to import and run LSTM layers correctly?  Thanks very much!

(A similar question came up in July of 2019, but I haven't seen an answer.)

Answer (score 1):

I came into this two days ago, and I found several things:

1. tf.keras.layers.LSTM in tf1 and tf2 has different default parameters for 'recurrent_activation', in tf1 this parameter defaults to 'hard_sigmoid', while in tf2 defaults to 'sigmoid'
2. tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockCell and tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockFusedCell have different weight orders with the weights in tf.keras.layers.LSTM

For Blocked LSTMs, the order is [Wi, Wci, Wf, Wo]

For LSTM, the order is [Wi, Wf, Wci, Wo]
The order of bias is consistent with that of wieght.

As for your problem, I think you should adjust the order of weight and bias before loading them in tf2 LSTM.

Simply, by equations:

```
xh = [x, h_prev]
```

In tf.keras.layers.LSTM

```
[i, f, ci, o] = xh * W + b
```

In tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMBlockCell

```
[i, ci, f, o] = xh * W + b
```

the following calculation are the same:

```
f = f + forget_bias
if not use_peephole:
  wci = wcf = wco = 0

i = sigmoid(cs_prev * wci + i)
f = sigmoid(cs_prev * wcf + f)
ci = tanh(ci)

cs = ci .* i + cs_prev .* f
cs = clip(cs, cell_clip)

o = sigmoid(cs * wco + o)
co = tanh(cs)
h = co .* o
```

At the last, code with numpy functions:

```
# kernel in LSTMBlockCell (shape is [input_size + units, 4 * units])
def adjust_order(var):
  i, ci, f, o = np.split(var, 4, axis=-1)
  return np.concatenate([i, f, ci, o], axis=-1)
new_kernel = adjust_order(kernel)
new_bias = adjust_order(bias)

lstm_layer.set_weights([new_kernel[:input_size, :], new_kernel[input_size:, :], bias])
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer - due to my subsequent errors in processing, I am not sure this solves my Checkpoint read problem, but I didn't feel it polite to let you wait without any response.

Comment: Thank you. My experience is to get a minimal issue and dive into it, I think that can solve any problem.